# How do I remove the "library root" setting from a directory?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rubymine

I use RubyMine.

When I created a project, a directory was automatically set to the "library root" as shown below.
[image]

I would like to remove this library root, but I could not find a way to do so in my search.
(I also tried the method in the following article, but it did not solve my case)

The environment settings (project configuration) are as follows
[image]

If you know how to unlock the LIBRARY route, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to `Project Structure` (Press `CMD + ;` on MacOS)
- Select `Platform Setting` - `SDKs`.
- Click your SDK name you are using.
- Check if the directory make as **"library root"** is under `Classpath`. Remove it if yes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change it by modifying .idea/.〇〇.iml

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure that the ancestor of the 'library root' folder is marked as 'excluded.'

Second, use the 'Repair IDE' under the 'File' tab to reindex all the files.

- Step 1: Rescan Project Indexes
- Step 2: Reopen Project
- Step 3: Drop Shared Indexes
- Step 4: Reindex Project

Last, wait for all the steps to be finished.
Then the 'library root' label should disappear.

Comment: Maybe in some cases but there are project setups (just to name one, a Flutter project with an internal plugin defined inside the project) where it does show it and no Repair will get rid of it because it seems intentional, even if wrong.